# How to ensure ordering of response for two different nodes in gremlin?

Tags: gremlin

For my data model, I have the following:

1. type defines an item
2. The project owns an item
3. Type is connected to anchors (Suppose the anchor is country)
4. Item is connected to a particular anchor instance (anchor instance
   will have corresponding value for anchor, suppose US)

I am trying to read an item along with the type, `anchorNames` and `anchorValues`.

Following is the query I have written:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Type').as('t')
.outE('DEFINES').inV().hasLabel('Item').has('dataId',’test-id').has('version','1').as('i')
.inE('OWNS').outV().hasLabel('Project').select('i')
.project('i','t','anchorNames','anchorValues')
.by(__.valueMap(true))
.by(__.in().hasLabel('Type').valueMap(true))
.by(out().in().hasLabel('Anchor').values('name').fold())
.by(out().as('AnchorInstance').select('AnchorInstance')
.by(values('value','secondaryValue').fold()).fold())
```

I get `i` and `t` but the result for `anchorNames` and `anchorValues` is as follows:

```
{anchorNames=[status, status, country], anchorValues=[[OK], [US], [FAIL]]}
```

However I am expecting the following:

```
{anchorNames=[status, status, country], anchorValues=[[OK], [FAIL], [US]]}
```

I need the ordering between the `anchorNames` and `anchorValues` as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach will be to get the name and the corresponding values together.

```
g.V().hasLabel('Type').as('t')
.out('DEFINES').hasLabel('Item').has('dataId',’test-id').has('version','1').as('i')
.in('OWNS').hasLabel('Project').select('i')
.project('i','t','anchors')
.by(__.valueMap(true))
.by(__.in().hasLabel('Type').valueMap(true))
.by(out().project('anchorNames','anchorValues')
    .by(__.in().hasLabel('Anchor').values('name'))
    .by(values('value','secondaryValue').fold()).fold())
```